# Conflicting font alignment depending on where class library is called from

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

This is more a question out of curiosity than necessity:

### Situation

I've been developing a class library that, in part, has a form that generates a "grid" of buttons with a label at the top of each column of buttons. The generation of these buttons is all done dynamically through code. The buttons are formatted so they all align in a "matrix-like" style and are added to a panel. Inside each of the buttons I have a text value ("1" to "5"). The header labels running along the top has the analysis-year text (something like "01" to "60" or "001" to "100" depending on the years of analysis specified by the user - I match the number of digits so that it all aligns nicely). Output looks something like this:

[image: good output]

When I call this library and test it in a developer environment everything looks fine (as shown above). Odd thing is, when I compile and deploy this library into the main application the text becomes truncated and it no longer fits within its control, like so:

[image: bad output]

I know windows forms are pretty-awful at handling resolutions and resizing of controls but I can't understand why this would be happening only once deployed. Perhaps I'm inheriting some font size from the main application - but I can't understand why that would override the explicit font set in the code?

### Code

```vb
Private Const PAD = 15                          '//Spacing around controls
Private _runningYearWidth As integer
Private _xPoints As List(Of Integer)
Private _yPoints As List(Of Integer)
Private Sub GenerateMatrix()
    Dim n = _profile.ComponentProfiles.Count    '//y-values
    Dim m = _AnalysisPeriod                     '//x-values

    '//Generate component labels
    '.....   

    '//Generate year labels
    _xPoints = New List(Of Integer)
    _runningYearWidth = PAD
    For i = 1 To m
        Dim lbl As New Label
        FormatYearLabel(lbl, i, i.ToString)
    Next

    '//Generate matrix buttons
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To m
            Dim btn As New Button
            '//N.B. This function only generates the buttons and aligns them in a grid. 
            '//The model needs to run in order to populate these controls with values
            FormatMatrixButton(btn, j, i)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Readonly _yearFont = New Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
Private Sub FormatYearLabel(l As Label, index As Integer, yearText As string)
    const y = 5
    Dim x = _runningYearWidth
    yearText = FormatYearText(yearText)            '//Returns "01" for year(1) if analysis years is 2 digits long
    Dim w = GetFontWidth(_yearFont, yearText) + 2  '//+1 pixel either side
    Dim h = GetFontHeight(_yearFont, yearText) + 2 '//+1 pixel either side
    With l
        .Font = _yearFont
        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
        .Width = w
        .Height = h
        .Text = yearText
        .Location = New Point(x, y)
        .Name = String.Format("lblYear{0}", index)
    End With
    panelMatrixDeterioration.Controls.Add(l)
    _runningYearWidth += (w + PAD)  '//X Co-Ord for next year-label
    _xPoints.AddRange({l.left, l.right})
End Sub

Private Function GetFontWidth(f As Font, txt As String) As Integer
    Dim g = panelMatrixComponents.CreateGraphics()
    Return g.MeasureString(txt, f).Width
End Function

Private Readonly _matrixFont = New Font("Consolas", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
Private Sub FormatMatrixButton(b As Button, x As Integer, y As Integer)
    '//Get this button's alignment points associated with the previously generated axis-labels
    Dim topleft = New Point(_xPoints((x-1)*2), _yPoints((y-1)*2))
    Dim bottomRight = New Point(_xPoints((x-1)*2 + 1), _yPoints((y-1)*2 + 1))
    With b
        .Font = _matrixFont
        .Location = topleft
        .Width = (bottomRight.X - topleft.X)
        .Height = (bottomRight.Y - topleft.Y)
        .Name = String.Format("btn{0}_{1}", x, y)
        .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        AddHandler .Click, AddressOf MatrixButton_Click
    End With
    panelMatrixDeterioration.Controls.Add(b)
End Sub

'//===============Run Model....
```

Fundamentally, what the code above shows is that the size (bounds) of the labels are based on a measured width of the text in each label. The size (bounds) of the buttons in the matrix are aligned with the labels at the headers or "axis".

N.B. the above doesn't show the y-axis (_yPoints) but the logic is fairly similar to the x-axis.

### Finally

For now I've done a quick fix and added some additional spacing around each control and when I compile the library and run it in the deployed application it looks fine - just slightly larger.

*What I would like to know is why there are different visual behaviours that only becomes apparent depending on where the library was being called from?*

Comment: I also do a lot of creating controls dynamically in the WinForms environment.  I often have to set `this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Inherit;` at the form level to get things like this to look correctly in different environments.  I can't guarantee this will fix your issue as it isn't exactly the behavior I experience.  But this setting has saved me from some bang my head on the desk moments over the years.

Comment: Try `AutoScaleMode.Inherit` or `AutoScaleMode.Font` (what the WinForms designer uses) or `.None` but you'll likely lose some functionality with that.

Comment: @jaredbaszler thanks for the suggestions. I've tried both `.Inherit`, `.Font` and `.None` but I'm still getting the same results when deployed.

Comment: Maybe it is just a padding and/or margin issue on the label control.  It looks like the labels are just being padded on the top by a 1-3 pixes.  Try explicitly setting both properties `.Padding` and `.Margin`.  This doesn't explain why this changes between environments but it might fix it without having to tweak the controls size to make it work.  Also, if you have any custom/user controls anywhere make sure to set `AutoScaleMode` within the creation of those controls as well.